# How do I find records that are inserted in the last four hours? - (Oracle SQLPLUS)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

This is regarding Oracle SQLPLUS query language.

```
   SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE record_date > time_4_hours_ago;
```

I have tried several methods, described on net and all of them did not work for me.
Tied UNIX_SYSTEM_TIME as well.

Problem seems a pretty common one, but I am struggling to get a solution that works with "Oracle" SQLPLUS.

Comment: time 4 hours ago = `sysdate - 4/24`

Comment: You're looking not for a *solution that works with "Oracle" SQLPLUS* but for solution that works with Oracle's SQL dialect.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming record_date is a DATE field:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE record_date > sysdate - (4/24)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
  from mytable
 where record_date > sysdate - interval '240' minute
```

Comment: Thanks. That works.  How do I deal with time-differences?  It seems the server is located in US but the records are inserted from france with franc's local time.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid invalid datetime values due to time zone differences you should override (record_date) value at the server side "using a database trigger for example" so as to insert the correct datetime value.